# How to move existing swift UI files into new group folder

Tags: xcode, swiftui, organization, group

Im working on my first, somewhat robust swiftUI project. I'm learning as I go so initially, I just kept adding my new views into the precreated PreviewContent folder. I want to better organize my project and create some more group folders and move the common swiftUI views into those new folders. However, when I just start grabbing files and dropping them into their new folders it looks like I'm getting a bunch of reference errors. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: *…create some more group folders* Where? In Finder or in Xcode?

Comment: show the errors

Comment: in Xcode. I tried moving a swiftUI view called createFlashCard from the Preview Content group into a new group I created and got the following error when trying to view it CouldNotFindExecutionPointInBuiltGraphError<XcodeGraphSource, Any>: "Create Flash Card" not found in any targets

The preview provider "Create Flash Card" must belong to at least one target in the current scheme in order to use previews

Element: PreviewProviderExecutionPoint(definition: createFlashCard_Previews in createFlashCard.swift, destinationPreferences: Destination Preferences {
})

Comment: Please [edit] your question with additional information, don’t put it in the comments. See also [ask].

Comment: _PreviewContent_ is not for actual views, it's for previews and other development assets. You should instead create some root folder on the same level as _PreviewContent_ (e.g. _Sources_ ) and under it just create the folder structure that makes sense. Now when moving _files_ it's important to make sure that you understand what is _target_ and which files are included in which targets (this is what your error is about).

Comment: It might be that your project is quite messed up already. If so, I recommend creating a new project from App template, which will make the right, and simply create new file sin proper places, while copying content of the files from the old project